# I can't update my table with trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to fill the empty field in the table after I update that table but I am get this error :

```
#1442 - Can't update table 'services_offer' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

**How can I fix it?**

my trigger's query:

```
DELIMITER $$
Create trigger OfferSum 
after UPDATE
on Services_Offer
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE Services_Offer
    SET NEW.final_price = 
    (SELECT service_price from Services_Level
    where Services_Level.level_code= Services_Offer.level_code)*Services_Offer.service_size;

END$$
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a *before* update trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER OfferSum BEFORE UPDATE ON Services_Offer
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT NEW.final_price := sl.service_price * NEW.service_size
    FROM Services_Level sl
    WHERE sl.level_code = NEW.level_code;
END$$
```

Comment: Hi. I tested this error but I get a syntax error. like := and I edited to = but get another syntax error

Comment: @HasanCheraghi . . . Syntax error is rather vague and doesn't provide any useful information.  The code looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a trigger for this? It looks like the query above will result in and endless loop. Every time you update a row, it calls an update trigger which actually updates the table and thus triggers the trigger again and again and again until something crashes.

Instead, why don't you calculate and update the column withing the initial update. The query would look like this:

```
UPDATE Services_Offer 
SET 
    column1 = value1, 
    column2 = value2, 
    final_price = 
      ( 
        SELECT service_price 
        FROM Services_Level 
        WHERE Services_Level.level_code = Services_Offer.level_code
      ) * service_size
WHERE id = XXX
```

where column1 = value1, column2 = value2 comes from your initial update query.